# Rails - Issue in has_many through with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I am having issue with saving a has_many through relation with nested attributes. Due to complexity and requirment in the application the relation is as follows

Table structure,

```
agreements:
  id

agreement_rooms:
  id
  agreement_id
  room_id

details:
  id
  agreement_rooms_id
```

For more clarification, agreement_rooms table is related to many other models which will be having agreement_rooms_id in them.

Rails Associations,

```
class Agreement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :details,:through => :agreement_rooms
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :details
end

class AgreementRoom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :details
end

class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agreement_room
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :agreement_room
end
```

When i try to create a agreements record with details hash in it, i get the following error,

```
Agreement.last.details.create()

ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection: Cannot modify association 'agreement#details' because the source reflection class 'Detail' is associated to 'agreementRoom' via :has_many.
```

I am not sure how to get this nested attributed working with has_many through relation for the above example. Please help out to figure the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your table structure and the associations doesn't match the **has-may-through**. I suggest you to follow these [**Guides**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Comment: @pavan, I understand its not up to the standards, but the existing design is in the way which cant be modified for now. So i just need a solution for now to get this working so later it can be designed as per the standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#app/models/aggreement.rb
class Agreement < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :agreement_rooms
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :agreement_rooms
end

#app/models/agreement_room.rb
class AgreementRoom < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :agreement
   belongs_to :room

   has_many :details
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :details
end

#app/models/room.rb
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :agreement_rooms
   has_many :agreements, through: :agreement_rooms
end

#app/models/detail.rb
class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :agreement_room
end
```

--

```
#app/controllers/agreements_controller.rb
class AgreementsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @agreement = Agreement.new
      @agreement.agreement_rooms.build.details.build
   end

   def create
      @agreement = Agreement.new agreement_params
      @agreement.save
   end

   private

   def agreement_params
      params.require(:agreement).permit(:agreement, :param, agreement_rooms_attributes: [ details_attributes: [:x] ])
   end
end

#app/views/agreements/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @agreement do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :agreement_rooms do |ar| %>
      <%= ar.fields_for :details do |d| %>
         <%= d.text_field :x %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me because my association was breaking has_many through standards. But for a proper has_many through association this solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define both associations:

```
class Agreement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :agreement_rooms # or has_many if you prefer
  has_many :details,:through => :agreement_rooms
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :details
end
```

check [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Answer (score 0):

As i said before the model association design we has was not proper and due to poor maintenance it has to be in the same way, atleast for now. So i had to write a dirty patch to fix it.

Its simply skipping nested attributes for this specific model alone, so it can be saved separately by passing the master record id to this record.

As its a dirty solution i'm not marking it as the answer. Just added it hoping someone can have a solution if needed.

Thanks for the help